Why does Bundle have no effect when calling contentResolver.query?
This code gives me the call log results in Ascending order instead of descending order and the results are not limited. Does anyone know why? It looks like the Bundle has no effect.
val strFields = arrayOf( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,  CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,  CallLog.Calls.DATE,  CallLog.Calls.DURATION,  CallLog.Calls.TYPE)
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putStringArray(
                    android.content.ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SORT_COLUMNS,
                    arrayOf(CallLog.Calls.DATE)
                )
                putInt(android.content.ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SORT_ORDER , android.content.ContentResolver.QUERY_SORT_DIRECTION_DESCENDING)
                putInt(android.content.ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT, 10)
            }

            val logs = context.contentResolver.query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                strFields,
                bundle, null)
            val numberIndex = logs!!.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)
            val nameIndex = logs.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)
            val typeIndex = logs.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE)
            val dateIndex = logs.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE)
            val durationIndex = logs.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION)
            while (logs.moveToNext()) {
               
            }


I never saw a Bundle used there. ContentValues.

I changed to bundle because they don't allow to use limit anymore without a bundle. It gives an exception.

This code worked instead:
        val logs = context.contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(CallLog.Calls.LIMIT_PARAM_KEY, "1")
                .build(),
            strFields,
            null,
            null,
            "date DESC"
        )

